# reset user login session in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-cookies

I store user auth info and token in a `cookie` locally for my `angular/typescript` SPA. Cookie expires after a certain time I have set. How do I reset expiration while user's activity? (session on the server is reset on users requests)

I mean what would be the best way, so I don't code some stupid stuff.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do your authentication and generation of the cookie on the server and your angular side authentication is located in a service.

One way to achieve what you are looking for is to create a method in your client side service to send a request to a known end point of the server which would refresh the cookie. This server endpoint will refresh the cookie and will return a HTTP 200 code.

Once you have this code in place, you can call it when the user interact with the application (ex navigation across views via `$locationChangeStart, $routeChangeStart` etc).

Comment: sry I didn't write down all the details... authentication is done on the server side of course where session is set and token is sent back to front-end where I save it into the cookie. Session's validity on the server is reset/renewed whenever user makes a request. Then I have to reset my local cookie which contains auth token. How? $routeChangeStart is an option, not sure if it's the best here